# Rails 4.0 - assets path changes based on route?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

In my `application.rb` file, I have the following:

`config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets')`

In my `routes.rb` file, I have this:

`root 'admin#index'`

That works perfectly fine. All of my assets are loaded correctly, and they are referenced like this in the html file:

`assets/stylesheets/...`

Now, if I try to do this, the assets are not found because it is looking for the wrong url:

`get 'admin/sign_in' => 'admin#sign_in'`

When I navigate to `localhost:3000/admin/sign_in`, I get a bunch of 404 errors. The assets are trying to load at:

`localhost:3000/admin/assets/....`

Why do the assets try to load at `/admin/assets` when I navigate to a custom route, but when navigating to the root route they loaded at `/assets`?

EDIT:

My `application.html.erb` is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Website</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 2:**

I am using a theme, and my html files all look similar to this right now:

```
<link href='assets/images/meta_icons/favicon.ico' rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon'>
    <link href='assets/images/meta_icons/apple-touch-icon.png' rel='apple-touch-icon-precomposed'>
    <link href='assets/images/meta_icons/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png' rel='apple-touch-icon-precomposed' sizes='57x57'>
    <link href='assets/images/meta_icons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png' rel='apple-touch-icon-precomposed' sizes='72x72'>
    <link href='assets/images/meta_icons/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png' rel='apple-touch-icon-precomposed' sizes='114x114'>
    <link href='assets/images/meta_icons/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png' rel='apple-touch-icon-precomposed' sizes='144x144'>
    <!-- / START - page related stylesheets [optional] -->

    <!-- / END - page related stylesheets [optional] -->
    <!-- / bootstrap [required] -->
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- / theme file [required] -->
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/light-theme.css" media="all" id="color-settings-body-color" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- / coloring file [optional] (if you are going to use custom contrast color) -->
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/theme-colors.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- / demo file [not required!] -->
    <link href="assets/stylesheets/demo.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="assets/javascripts/ie/html5shiv.js"
              type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="assets/javascripts/ie/respond.min.js"
              type="text/javascript"></script>
      <![endif]-->





<!-- / jquery [required] -->
    <script src="assets/javascripts/jquery/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- / jquery mobile (for touch events) -->
    <script src="assets/javascripts/jquery/jquery.mobile.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- / jquery migrate (for compatibility with new jquery) [required] -->
    <script src="assets/javascripts/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- / jquery ui -->
    <script src="assets/javascripts/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- / jQuery UI Touch Punch -->
    <script src="assets/javascripts/plugins/jquery_ui_touch_punch/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- / bootstrap [required] -->
    <script src="assets/javascripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- / modernizr -->
    <script src="assets/javascripts/plugins/modernizr/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- / retina -->
    <script src="assets/javascripts/plugins/retina/retina.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- / theme file [required] -->
    <script src="assets/javascripts/theme.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- / demo file [not required!] -->
    <script src="assets/javascripts/demo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- / START - page related files and scripts [optional] -->
    <script src="assets/javascripts/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/javascripts/plugins/validate/additional-methods.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- / END - page related files and scripts [optional] -->
```

Comment: Please show the part of your layout that includes the assets (i.e. where you call [`stylesheet_link_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-stylesheet_link_tag))

Comment: @DMKE I added my application.html.erb which is the only mention of the stylesheet_link_tag code. I also confirmed that if you route to `get 'sign_in'` instead of `get 'admin/sign_in'` the problem is resolved.

Comment: That's strange. Do you include your stylesheet anywhere else in any other way (e.g. manually inserting a `<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/application.css" />`)?

Comment: @DMKE I am using a bootstrap theme, which I'm sure has something to do with it. I edited my post to contain an example of how all of the required assets are currently laid out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the files from `.html` to `.html.erb` and use a `stylesheet_link_tag` for requiring the assets:

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag "light-theme" %>`

This should solve the issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Rails serves assets at `/assets/image-name.jpg`, `/assets/stylesheet-name.css` and `/assets/application.js` and no9t `assets/images/meta_icons/apple-touch-icon.png` like you wrote.

GET 'admin/sign_in', it's looking for a sign_in.html.erb template in `views/admin/`